# JRuby 1.7.15, Rails 4, pry, debugger

Tags: debugging, jruby, jrubyonrails, pry

Recently, i have migrated my application on Ruby on Rails 4 to JRuby 1.7.15 with Rails 4.

when i execute bundle, I have got following error :

An error occurred while installing debugger (1.6.8), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install debugger -v '1.6.8'` succeeds before bundling.

I understand, debugger doesn't work with JRuby. But how use "gem pry" with JRuby ?

Thank for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using pry with jruby is not different from using it with any other ruby and the debugger gem is not neccesary. The pry ecosystem is also a much superior solution.

Using pry with rails is most easiest with 'pry-rails' gem. Just add it to your Gemfile than call

```
binding.pry
```

at any place in your code in order to set a breakpoint

Comment: I removed pry-debugger in my gemfile, i kept pry-rails and bundle has been correctly executed. thank dre-hh

Answer (score 2):

'pry-debugger' doesn't work with jRuby, but the gem 'pry-nav' does. I'm using pry-nav right now but I'm looking for a debugger that has a little more functionality.